# How does EF Core DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed work on GUID property

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration, ef-core-3.1

I have a `Team` entity that has a `GUID TeamId` property that I want to auto generate the values On Add when saving it to database (Note that property is NOT the primary key).

Am using EFCore 3.1.6 & the backend is SqlServer.

Based on the MS docs the value generation on Add depends on the database provider and it should be autogenerated for sql server - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add. Now when I save a new Team, it fails because the TeamId wasn't auto generated but it is a Not Null field in the database.

**Question:** Shouldn't EFCore migrations setup default value for this TeamId field just by inferring it from the annotations? Or do I need to use `HasDefaultValueSql("NewId()")` in the `OnModelCreating` for this field?

If the `HasDefaultValueSql("NewId()")` was the missing piece then what is the point of the annotation?

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The table created by efcore database migration:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Teams](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TeamId] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Teams] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: as far as i remember ef will create fluent configuration from data annotations only if there is no fluent configuration attached already.. If you use both together your code will become inconsistent. So use any one, either Data Annotations Or Fluent API. Calling modelBuilder.Entity<Team>() will actually create an EntityTypeConfiguration<Team> and return it to you, so whichever approach you choose, you are accessing the same API.

Comment: that is my expectation too - using either annotations or fluent api - not both. However, using just the annotations in this case didn't help. however just the fluent api worked in my scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of the following Fluent API statements will work in your case (non-PK and SQL Server):

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.TeamId)
    .HasValueGenerator<SequentialGuidValueGenerator>();

entity.Property(e => e.TeamId)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())");

entity.Property(e => e.TeamId)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");
```

For a `Guid` property that is the primary key, the data annotation `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and the Fluent API call `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` will work too. Both will use the `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` (not the default value).

Comment: the Guid field in question wasn't a primary key in my entity - I just wanted the value to be auto-generated. And based on my finding only the FluentApi works not the data annotation of DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed or Identity

Comment: That is correct and is exactly what my answer says. The three shown method calls will work in your case described here, where the property in question is not a primary key. The data annotation (that translates to a Fluent API `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` call) will only work for primary keys.